# Is 「用」the kanji for 「よう」in the listed phrases?

Tags: kanji, phrases

Is 用 the kanji used for よう in these phrases?:

> 1) 事故のようですね。
>
> 2) もう帰ったようです。
>
> 3) 私のようにして下さい。
>
> 4) 試験にごうかくしますように。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In all these expressions, よう, *if* written in Kanji, would be 様 (though it's kind of uncommon). In the first two phrases, it means 'it seems'. They mean 'It seems to be an accident' and 'It seems he/she/they have already gone home'. In the third phrase, it means 'like': 'Make it like me' (?). In the last phrase, it's part of the set phrase ～ますように, expressing a wish, desire, or hope: 'I hope I/you/he/she/they pass the test'.